# Problems with Spring MVC 4.0 application with Restful routing and AngularJS routing

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a Spring MVC 4.0 AngularJS application that seems to have collisions between the Restful interface routing, and the AngularJS routing when running on the same instance. It causes 404 errors. I dont think I have the application setup correctly.

The application is bundled into a UserManager.war file and copied into the webapps directory on a Tomcat 7.0 instance running stand-alone (not embedded in an IDE).

The application runs at:

```
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/main
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/update
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/insert
```

And the restful interfaces specifies these urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/list
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/{id}
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/insert
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/update/{id}
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/delete/{id}
```

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
<display-name>User Manager Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Here is my **rest-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="localhost.rest.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Here is my **UserManagerControler.java**:

```
package localhost.rest.controller;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class UserManagerControler{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getUsers() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{pid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getUserById(@PathVariable String pid) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/insert", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/update/{pid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable String pid, @RequestBody User user) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/delete/{pid}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public  ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable String pid) {

    }

}
```

Here is my **app.js** which sets up the AngularJS routing:

```
angular.module('PMApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'PMApp.services' ])
.config(
        [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
                function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                    $routeProvider.when('/main', {
                        controller : 'MainController',
                        templateUrl : 'app/partials/main.html'
                    }).when('/insert', {
                        controller : 'InsertController',
                        templateUrl : 'app/partials/insert.html'
                    }).when('/update', {
                        controller : 'UpdateController',
                        templateUrl : 'app/partials/update.html'
                    }).otherwise({
                        redirectTo : '/main'
                    });

                } ]

).run(function($rootScope, $window, $location) {
    $rootScope.initialized = true;
});
```

The controllers are setup in the controller.js file, and calls to my restful webservice are performed in a services.js file.

**services.js**:

```
(function () {
    var userService = function ($http, $window, $q, $log, $rootScope) {

        var factory = {};

        factory.createUser = function (userId, last, first, sex, age, ethnicity, rank, dob) {
            var url = '/UserManager/services/users/insert';

            var parameters = {
                "userId" : userId,
                "last" : last,
                "first" : first,
                "sex" : sex,
                "age" : age,
                "ethnicity" : ethnicity,
                "rank" : rank,
                "dob" : dob
            };

            return $http.put(url, parameters)
                .then(function (data, status) {
                    return data;
                });
        };

        factory.deleteUser = function(userId) {
            var url = '/UserManager/services/users/delete/' + userId;
            return $http.delete(url)
                .then(function (data, status) {
                    return data;
                });
        };

        factory.updateUser = function (userId, last, first, sex, age, ethnicity, rank, dob) {
            var url = '/UserManager/services/users/update/' + userId;


            var parameters = {
                "userId" : userId,
                "last" : last,
                "first" : first,
                "sex" : sex,
                "age" : age,
                "ethnicity" : ethnicity,
                "rank" : rank,
                "dob" : dob
            };

            return $http.post(url, parameters)
                .then(function (data, status) {
                    return data;
                });
        };

        factory.getUsers = function () {
            var url = '/UserManager/services/users/list';

            return $http.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        };

        factory.getUser = function (userId) {
            var url = '/UserManager/services/users/' + userId;

            return $http.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        };

        return factory;
    }

    var app = angular.module("PMApp.services", ['ngResource']);
    app.factory('userService', userService);
}());
```

I can get the webservice to work, but then I get 404 error on the application.  If I tweak my web.xml, I can get the application to start up, but then calls to the webservice fail with a 404 error.

Comment: can you post your services definition that calls the webservice?

Comment: why not use $resource instead of $http ? Since you're dealing with REST endpoints

Comment: Im not sure other than the various examples of code I looked at used $http, not $resource.

Comment: @MLefebvre - Did you find any solution for this..Even I am facing the same..

Answer (score 0):

try changing your var to:

```
url = '/{webapp-name}/services/users/insert'
```

try to use a rest test tool like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/app/11-web-development
to check if you're RESTful endpoint is accessible and returning Mime type application/json

also for debugging purposes it might help placing an error handling block like:

```
       $http.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }).error(function () {               
            // error happened           
       });
```

and also check your browser's console and the server's log files to see if there's any error message showing up.

Also since you're dealing with RESTful endpoints why not try $resource instead of $http like in example:

service:

```
services.factory('ProductService', ['$resource',
  function($resource){  
    return $resource('/mywebapp/rest/product/:id',
            {
            id: "@id"           
            }
    );
  }]);
```

controller:

```
controllers.controller('ProductListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProductService',
  function($scope, ProductService) {

    ProductService.query(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.productListNotEmpty = ($scope.products.length > 0);
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: The code above works for the webservice, but the ANgularJS routing doesnt work giving 404.  If I change my web.xml file from /* to any other path, then the AngularJS routing works, but the RESTService get 404.

The error coming back is 404 error.  When I try to access the restful service directly using SoapUI I get a 404 as well.  Also, in a browser if I hit it directly I get a 404 error.

Comment: I guess your webservice path might be wrong, are you sure your REST URLs are accessible and returning application/json Mime type? check my updated answer

Comment: Made the change and the Webservice is still working fine returning JSON values, and has status of 200, but the application routing is still not working and giving 404. http://localhost:8080/UserManager/main does not work currently.  I tried http://localhost:8080/UserManager/#/main as well and no luck.

Comment: whats the url working for you in spring ? And what's the URL that angular is trying to access? Can you verify under the Network tabs?

Comment: As stated above:
The application runs at:

http://localhost:8080/UserManager/main
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/update
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/insert
And the restful interfaces specifies these urls:

http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/list
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/{id}
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/insert
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/update/{id}
http://localhost:8080/UserManager/services/users/delete/{id}

Comment: These are the same ones that the application is trying to use according to the network tab.

Comment: Could this be a tomcat configuration issue?

Comment: I don't think tomcat would be an issue since you said you can access them, I would be trying with $resource instead of $http as in example in answer